# Program completes even before completing all the Jobs and CPU memory continues to increase

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-ise

I have created a PowerShell Program to execute multiple sql script files:
Below is my code in PS:

```
cls
$SQLSERVER = 'Servername'
$DATABASE = 'DB'
$USERNAME = 'Username'
$Password = 'Password'

$FileThreadCount = 5

$pwd = Get-Location
write-host $pwd
$importLog = [string]$pwd+"\LogFile.ps1"
import-module $importLog
#import-module F:\1022769\LogFile.ps1


$LogDateTime = Get-Date -Format "dd-mm-yyyy HH-mm-ss"
$LogFolder = [string]$pwd+"\log"
$logFile = $LogFolder+'\output'+$LogDateTime+'.txt'
Write-Host "Program Started"

if (Test-Path -Path $LogFolder)
{
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Program started" -UseMutex $true
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Log Folder created $LogFolder" -UseMutex $true
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Log File created $logFile" -UseMutex $true
}
else
{
    New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $LogFolder
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Program started" -UseMutex $true
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Log Folder created $LogFolder" -UseMutex $true
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Log File created $logFile" -UseMutex $true
}


$ProcessedFolder = [string]$pwd+"\out"
if (Test-Path -Path $ProcessedFolder)
{}
else
{
    New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $ProcessedFolder
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Processed folder created $ProcessedFolder" -UseMutex $true
}

$InputFolder = [string]$pwd+"\in"

if (Test-Path -Path $InputFolder)
{}
else
{
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Input Folder not found, create a folder in the program directory naming In and add .sql files in it" -UseMutex $true
    Exit
}

$FileCount = (Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter *.sql | Measure-Object ).Count
if ($FileCount -le 0 )
{
    Write-Host "Total Files in folder $InputFolder are $FileCount" 
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Total Files in folder $InputFolder are $FileCount" -UseMutex $true
    Exit
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Total Files in folder $InputFolder are $FileCount"
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Total Files in folder $InputFolder are $FileCount" -UseMutex $true
    $myString = "This is session state!"
    $sessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()
    $sessionstate.Variables.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry -ArgumentList "myString" ,$myString, "example string"))
    # Create runspace pool consisting of $numThreads runspaces
    $RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $FileThreadCount, $sessionState, $Host)
    $RunspacePool.Open()
    $Jobs = @()
    Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter *.sql | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $content =  $_.FullName
        $FileName = $_.name 
        $DatetimeA = Get-Date -DisplayHint DateTime
    
        $Job = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($fnStartQueryExe).AddParameter("importLog", $importLog).AddParameter("content", $content).AddParameter("FileName", $FileName).AddParameter("ProcessedFolder", $ProcessedFolder).AddParameter("SQLSERVER", $SQLSERVER).AddParameter("DATABASE", $DATABASE).AddParameter("USERNAME", $USERNAME).AddParameter("Password", $Password).AddParameter("logFile", $logFile)
        $Job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
        $Jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          RunNum = $_
          Job = $Job
          Result = $Job.BeginInvoke()
       }
}
Write-Host "Waiting.."
Do {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} While ( $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)
}
$DatetimeEndProgram = Get-Date -DisplayHint DateTime
Write-Host "$DatetimeEndProgram Program Completed"
write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Program completed" -UseMutex $true
Pause
    
$fnStartQueryExe={
Param ([string]$importLog,[string]$content,
[string]$FileName, [string]$ProcessedFolder, [string]$SQLSERVER, [string]$DATABASE, [string]$USERNAME, [string]$Password, [string]$logFile)

 import-module $importLog
    write-host 'FileName '$content
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "FileName '$content Started execution" -UseMutex $true
    $output=echo exit|SQLCMD -S $SQLSERVER -d $DATABASE -U $USERNAME -P $Password -h -1 -i $content
    write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "FileName '$content End execution" -UseMutex $true
    
    if (Test-Path -Path $ProcessedFolder) 
    {
        $filePath = $ProcessedFolder+"\"+$FileName
        
            if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath))
            {
                write-host 'File Already exists, overwriting ' $filePath
                write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "File Already exists, overwriting $filePath" -UseMutex $true
                write-host 'Moving to '$filePath
                write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Moving to '$filePath" -UseMutex $true
                Move-Item -Path $content -Destination $filePath -force
                write-host 'Moved to '$filePath
                write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Moved to '$filePath" -UseMutex $true
            }
            else
            {
                write-host 'Moving to '$filePath
                write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Moving to '$filePath" -UseMutex $true
                Move-Item -Path $content -Destination $filePath
                write-host 'Moved to '$filePath
                write-log -log $logFile -level INFO -text "Moved to '$filePath" -UseMutex $true
            }
    } 
    else 
    {
        write-host "File Executed but not moved to out folder as the output path does not exists"
    }
}
```

Program has no issues, but problem arises when I run the program from the PowerShell ISE, for the **First Time** it completes even before completing all the Jobs and Even after stopping the program, the memory and CPU usage keeps on increasing: Please check below Screen Shots

[[image: ProgramStartedEndedBeforeJobCompletion][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2JlC.png)]

[[image: TaskManagerMemoryCPUIncrease][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qrxV.png)]

And **Second Time** when I run the program from the PowerShell ISE, it runs fine, and it waits for all the jobs to get complete

Also, when I run the program using CMD or right-clicking the program and Run with PowerShell, It again completes even before completing all the Jobs, but there is no task in task scheduler (meaning the program exists): Please check below Screen Shot

[[image: ProgramStartedEndedBeforeJobCompletionFromPSConsole][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX56T.png)]

Really appreciate if someone can suggest if I'm going wrong anywhere or missing anything

Comment: out of curiosity, does it make any difference moving `$fnStartQueryExe` to the top of the script?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response, but no, it doesn't, no difference if i move it to the top